# TS: Re-exporting a class scoped to a namespace

Tags: typescript

I would like to have a namespace be the hub of classes for a strategy in my system. The reason it has to be a namespace is that was the best way to do dynamic class generation, as the `window` object method proved fruitless.

I would like to re-export this file

```
// Bar.ts
export class Bar {
  public log() {console.log('I'm in Bar);}
}
```

from the following namespace as such

```
//Foo.ts
export namespace Foo {
  export Bar from './bar.ts' // <- how do I do this?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-export something you imported outside of the namespace:

```js
import * as BarFile from "./Bar";

export namespace Foo {
  export import Bar = BarFile.Bar;
}
```

There may be a better way to export it without the `import * as BarFile`, but I still use it this way.

Comment: Thanks a ton! A quick follow up question, what is the syntax `export import Bar = BarFile.Bar` ? Is there a document page you can quickly recommend to book up on that?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how I know that, I think I searched around when I faced this issue and then I have this code example on my project for some years now. I think this is an extrapolation from the import syntax `import _ = require('lodash');` applied to namespace's `export <statement>`.